# Adding to arrayLists and Changing font color

Tags: c#

I'm working on a homework problem.  I have to use an ArrayList.  I need to add an item to the list and it needs to be saved, so when I add another it shows up.  The previous entry isn't saving, should I create a string array to save the arraylist into?  When I type one of the three color names in, it should appear as that color.  The arraylist prints out to a label after you click the add button.  The instructions say to make the arraylist static.(A little confused by that because static means already set no?)  Here's what I have so far, please remember I'm just starting out.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList();
    itemList.Add("red");
    itemList.Add("blue");
    itemList.Add("green");
    itemList.Add(TextBox1.Text);

    string textToDisplay = string.Empty;

    foreach (object item in itemList)  //Getting an error here at the "in"
    {
         if (TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("red"))   // Should I use a switch statement?
         {
             itemList[0] = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         }
         if (TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("blue"))
         {
             itemList[1] = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
         }
         if (TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("green"))
         {
             itemList[2] = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
         }

             textToDisplay += item + "<br />";
         }

       ResultLabel.Text = textToDisplay;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting for this line `foreach (object item in itemList)`?

Comment: you are creating the array inside the method, it should be outside the function to retain the previous change.

Comment: Here is the error:An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize the array every time the button `Add` is clicked because it always have 4 colors at max and the order is fixed (red, blue, green, 1 more color).

And you can loop `foreach(string item in itemList)` instead of `foreach(object item in itemList)`

You can use this code to add new color to the `ResultLabel`

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string colorAdded = "";
    switch(TextBox1.Text) { 
        case "red":
            colorAdded = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case "blue":
            colorAdded = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            break;
        case "green":
            colorAdded = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            break;
        default:
            colorAdded = //Insert your default color here;
            break;
    }

    ResultLabel.Text += colorAdded + "<br/>";
}
```